# Tipos incompatíveis VBA - LookUp em outra planilha

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Olá

Estou com o erro "Tipos Incompatíveis" em uma macro que estou fazendo.

A minha planilha funciona da seguinte maneira: existe uma aba de ações (com botões onde ela chama as macros) e uma aba de produtos (com os cadastros completos dos meus produtos). Esta é a planilha principal, onde está o código. Existem as planilhas secundárias, com a movimentação dos produtos no mês, as quais eu preciso conferir alguns parâmetros mensalmente. A minha planilha principal possui um macro que permite eu selecionar a planilha secundária e fazer a conferência de alguns desses parâmetro, mas o problema ocorre quando eu preciso fazer a comparação entre a aba "Produtos" e a planilha secundária. A parte do código que está ocasionando o erro é a seguinte:

`cst = Application.VLookup(codigo_produto, Workbooks("Conferir ICMS.xlsm").Worksheets("Produtos").Range("A2:K99999"), 11, 0)`

"Conferir ICMS.xlsm" é minha planilha principal.

A variável "cst" está declarada como String.

Agradeço se alguém tiver uma luz para me dar, estou revirando fóruns a um bom tempo e não consegui encontrar onde estou errando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia, meu caro.

Fiz um teste, e creio que o problema é que VLookup não retorna sempre string. Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.vlookup), o valor de retorno é uma `Variant`. Se o seu `codigo_produto` contiver algum erro (como variável não definida), ou se for de um produto não encontrado na planilha com a lista, o retorno não será uma `String`, e sim um erro (daí o erro Tipos Incompatíveis).

**Para resolver**, ou você declara `cst` como `Variant` (o que é o mais simples e adequado) ou garante que todos os `codigo_produto` terão uma correspondência (o que é muito difícil e mesmo assim pode haver outros casos em que a função retornará algo que não uma string).

Ao declarar `cst` como `Variant`, ficará fácil descobrir qual o valor que não havia sido encontrado, pois `cst` conterá o erro, em vez do valor encontrado.

**Por fim, uma dica:** Se você quer referenciar as colunas inteiras de A até K, você pode simplesmente omitir os números, em vez de colocar um número arbitrariamente alto. Ou seja, poderia colocar `Workbooks("Conferir ICMS.xlsm").Worksheets("Produtos").Range("A:K")`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Segui suas dicas e realmente o valor de cst está retornando erro, acredito que o código não está encontrando o worksheet. Mas agora já tenho um "norte" para resolver o problema, assim que estiver solucionado eu posto aqui. Novamente, muito obrigado.